# Why does this constructor function not work? (In Ajax success)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, constructor

I'm trying to extract my json data and put into a variable, which is available from everywhere. But I've got an error message, it says :  foods is undefined (the row of the alert in the end)

```
  var foods;
          function search() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "foodsrequest.php",
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              async: false,
              data: {"inputData": JSON.stringify(filterdata)},
              success: function(data){

                foods = foodConstructor(data[0]); ///yes, it is an array of objects and it has all the parameters needed
                function foodConstructor(dataIn){
                  this.id = dataIn.id;
                  this.name = dataIn.name;
                  this.price = dataIn.price;
                  this.species = dataIn.species;
                  this.type = dataIn.type;
                  this.manufacturer = dataIn.manufacturer;
                  this.weight = dataIn.weight;
                  this.age = dataIn.age;
                  this.partner = dataIn.partner;
                }
              }
            });
          }

          alert(foods.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try invoking your constructor with **new** keyword. It will work.

`foods = new foodConstructor(data[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the new keyword

Try:

```
            foods = new foodConstructor ( data[ 0 ]); ///yes, it is an array of objects and it has all the parameters needed function foodConstructor ( dataIn ){ this . id = dataIn . id ; this . name = dataIn . name ; this . price = dataIn . price ; this . species = dataIn . species ; this . type = dataIn . type ; this . manufacturer = dataIn . manufacturer ; this . weight = dataIn . weight ; this . age = dataIn . age ; this . partner = dataIn . partner ; } } }); } 

      alert ( foods . name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Howard Fring what you are going to want to do is move the alert into a function and call it from the call back function that is called when the ajax request succeeds.  `food` is not populated until the request is finished that is why it is undefined.  For example:

```
var foods;
      function search() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "foodsrequest.php",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          data: {"inputData": JSON.stringify(filterdata)},
          success: function(data){

            foods = new foodConstructor(data[0]); ///yes, it is an array of objects and it has all the parameters needed
            function foodConstructor(dataIn){
              this.id = dataIn.id;
              this.name = dataIn.name;
              this.price = dataIn.price;
              this.species = dataIn.species;
              this.type = dataIn.type;
              this.manufacturer = dataIn.manufacturer;
              this.weight = dataIn.weight;
              this.age = dataIn.age;
              this.partner = dataIn.partner;
            }
            foodAlert();
          }
        });
      }

      function foodAlert(){
        alert(foods.name);
      }
```

By calling `foodAlert` in the `success` call back after food is populated will open an alert with the value of `food.name` shown.